# Debian based Raspberry – samba invisible unless I restart

Tags: debian, samba, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) along with other computers on the same network. I installed, configured and started [`samba`](http://www.samba.org/samba/) to share files from my home folder of the Raspberry Pi to my other computers.

It works really well, however I have a problem: Sometimes when I check the network to find my Raspberry Pi samba server, I don't see it. It appears as soon as I restart `samba` on the *RPI*.

1. Is there a way to launch a *"discovery"* of samba servers?
2. When I restart samba, does it send a broadcast signal to the network to say it is available?